# Call C dll from C#: Values of struct array remain unchanged

Tags: c#, c

I try very simple:

C:

```cpp
typedef struct {
  char        dummy[36] ;
} MAZ_TD ;

__declspec(dllexport) int MazGetAllToolData(unsigned short hnd1, unsigned short head, unsigned short num, MAZ_TD* data)
{
  int retvalue = 2;
  printf ("data[2].dummy before: %s\n", data[2].dummy);
  strcpy_s(data[2].dummy, "253");
  printf ("data[2].dummy after: %s\n", data[2].dummy);
  return retvalue;
}
```

```
data[2].dummy before: hgg
data[2].dummy after: 253
```

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MAZ_TD
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 36)]
    public string dummy;
};

[DllImport(TEST_DLL, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
unsafe public static extern int MazGetAllToolData(ushort hndl, ushort head, ushort num, MAZ_TD[] maz_td);

MAZ_TD[] m = new MAZ_TD[10];
m[2].dummy = "hgg";
ret = MazGetAllToolData((ushort)hndl, 0, (ushort)numberOfTools, m);
Debug.WriteLine("m[2].dummy: " + m[2].dummy);
```

```
m[2].dummy: hgg
```

The m[2].dummy remain unchanged ("hgg"). It should be "253".
What is wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `[In, Out] MAZ_TD[] m` in the managed declaration of `MazGetAllToolData`? It seems that the marshaller isn't bothering to marshal `m` back from the unmanaged code to the managed code, but I'm not entirely sure on what the rules are with passing arrays of structs

Comment: Yeah, looks like reference types are `In` by defaut: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/77e6taeh(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @canton7 yep, I'd overlooked that; I'd still like to see the `extern` though :)

Comment: Hallo canton7, Marc, thank you very much! ;) Thumbs up,, that was ist. And sorry, I forgot to show the declaration in C# 

now: 

`[DllImport(TEST_DLL, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`

`unsafe public static extern int MazGetAllToolData(ushort hndl, ushort head, ushort num, [In, Out] MAZ_TD[] maz_td);`

Comment: You are only initializing the array and not the instances in the array.  Try following MAZ_TD[] m = new MAZ_TD[10]; m[2] = new MAZ_TD();  m[2].dummy = "hgg";

Comment: jdweng: thanks for the hint, of course you are right. But that was not the problem here.

Comment: @jdweng It's an array of structs: they'll be default-initialized, no need to explicitly initialize them